# Google chart NumberRangeFilter SUM instead of filter?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there a way to force **NumberRangeFilter** to display the summed results of other rows in range?

As an example I have this table:

```
A | B | C
----------
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 3
3 | 2 | 1
4 | 0 | 1
5 | 0 | 0
```

If I implement a RangeFilter and set it from 2 to 4, I would like a chart to display the summed values of **B2:B4** and **C2:C4** fields.

***This is default functionality:*** [image]

***This is what I want to achieve:***
[image: Default functionality]

How can I achieve such a thing ?